# Java: Project Euler 41:Pandigital prime

Tags: java, primes

Problem: [Project Euler Problem 41](http://projecteuler.net/problem=41)
The following is the complete programme. My question is on one sentence of code.

```
public class Practice {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(double i=7654321;i>1234566;i-=2){
        if(isUnique(i)){
            if(isPrime(i)){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(double i=4321;i>1233;i-=2){
        if(isUnique(i)){
            if(isPrime(i)){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

static boolean isUnique(double num){
    String str = String.valueOf(num);
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        if(str.charAt(i)=='9'){return false;}
        if(str.charAt(i)=='8'){return false;}
        if(str.charAt(i)=='0'){return false;}  //<---***Sentence 1***
    }
    for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<str.length()-1;j++){
            if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j+1)){return false;}
        }
    }
    return true;
}

static boolean isPrime(double num){
    for(double i=3;i<=num/2;i+=2){
        if(num%i==0){return false;}
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

I got the correct answer if the Sentence 1 `(if(str.charAt(i)=='0'){return false;})`
is **NOT** included. If Sentence 1 is included, the programme terminates immediately. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `double`, all your `String`s are on the form

```
7654321.0
```

which all contain a `0`, ending the `isUnique()` calls immediately. Using an `int` instead makes more sense for investigating prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the debugger you can see that the value of your parameter  `double num`  is `7654321.0`

The `.0` causes the method to terminate. Solution: don't use a double but a long or int.